# Android Nougat ProcessBuilder ignores PATH env variable - bug/issue?

Tags: android, security, processbuilder, android-7.0-nougat, android-security

I'm having android app that extracts some native executable on first run and uses it to do some work. It worked before Nougat and stopped working. After few days or investigation i've found that PATH environment variable is accepted but not taken into account! I'm, trying out if it's a feature or a bug.

First, let's see what we have and if we're able to do the same from cmd.
I've replaced actual android app package with 'my.app.package' and not related output with '...' for SO.

```
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/ $ run-as my.app.package
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ whoami
u0_a129
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ ls -l
total 56
drwxrwx--x  2 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-14 16:15 app_build
drwxrwx--x  2 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-15 13:15 app_buildSources
drwxrwx--x  2 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-14 16:15 app_downloads
-rw-------  1 u0_a129 u0_a129   35 2017-03-14 16:16 app_repository
drwxrwx--x 14 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-14 16:16 app_sdk
drwxrwx--x  3 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-14 16:15 app_temp
drwxrwx--x  2 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-14 16:15 cache
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      54 2017-03-15 13:15 lib -> /data/app/my.app.package-2/lib/arm
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ ls -l ./app_sdk/                                                                                                    
total 96
...
drwx------ 4 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-14 16:16 cppcheck#1.64#1
...
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ ls -l ./app_sdk/cppcheck\#1.64\#1/                                                                                  
total 16
...
drwx------ 3 u0_a129 u0_a129 4096 2017-03-14 16:16 bin
-rw------- 1 u0_a129 u0_a129    0 2017-03-14 16:16 init.done
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ ls -l ./app_sdk/cppcheck\#1.64\#1/bin                                                                               
total 6960
drwx------ 2 u0_a129 u0_a129    4096 2017-03-14 16:16 cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 u0_a129 u0_a129 2345332 2017-03-14 16:16 cppcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 u0_a129 u0_a129 1211424 2017-03-14 16:16 libgnustl_shared.so
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ export PATH=$PATH:./app_sdk/cppcheck#1.64#1/bin
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./app_sdk/cppcheck#1.64#1/bin
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $ cppcheck --version
Cppcheck 1.65 dev
ZTE_BLADE_V0800:/data/data/my.app.package $
```

Now let's try to do the same in Runtime:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

String path =
  System.getenv("PATH") +
  ":./app_sdk/cppcheck#1.64#1/bin";
processBuilder.command(new String[] {
//      "sh", "-c", "echo $PATH", // (1) working
//      "sh", "-c", "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH", // (2) working
        "./app_sdk/cppcheck#1.64#1/bin/cppcheck", "--version" // (3) working
//      "cppcheck", "--version"                             // (4) NOT working even with PATH env variable passed
      });
processBuilder.directory(new File("/data/data/my.app.package/"));
Map<String, String> env = processBuilder.environment();
env.put("PATH", path);
env.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "./app_sdk/cppcheck#1.64#1/bin");
process = processBuilder.start();
```

and i get `IOException` thrown:

> Cause: error=13, Permission denied
>                                                                                 Cannot run program "cppcheck" (in directory
>   "/data/data/my.app.package"): error=13

Let's see if PATH is passed correctly.
Uncomment comment (1) and comment the other command lines, confirm it's set:

> /sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:./app_sdk/cppcheck#1.64#1/bin

Let's see if LD_LIBRARY_PATH is passed correctly.
Uncomment comment (2) and comment the other command lines, confirm it's set:

> ./app_sdk/cppcheck#1.64#1/bin

Now let's see if i'm able to run the tool passing **full path**.
Uncomment comment (3) and comment the other command lines, see it's working now:

> Cppcheck 1.65 dev

Wow, even with PATH passed i have to pass full path for the executable. If i use short tool name, i'm getting `Permission denied` error.

Is it Nougat (since i'm having it starting Nougat only) feature or issue or i missed anything?

I know Nougat introduced more strict security policies but i see no reason for this in my case to stop working as all the files are in app sandbox (internal directory in my app directory).

PS. I can't just replace all short executable names in command-lines as executable can run another executable too using short executable name, so i need to get PATH variable taken into account eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get any response from Google (they are working on it starting Jan 25) so i had to workaround it passing **full executable path** like in comment (3).

Comment: actually i got response from Google and it was a bug before Nougat and it should not work this way even before Nougat